# How to ignore all warnings with jshint?

Tags: javascript, jshint

Is it possible to ignore all warnings with jshint without making such a config file:

```
{
        ...
    "-W039": false
    "-W040": false
    "-W041": false
    "-W042": false
        ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, very easy: don't run it :)

Comment: If you want to ignore all warnings, why are you still using jshint? Surely, that's like buying a smoke detector and then removing the batteries...

Comment: I still want to see errors. So I let the battery in, but I reduce the detection level, so people can continue to smoke inside. Dangerous, but still useful.

Comment: So? Let the HUMANS ignore the warnings then, if you don't want to let jshint ignore those conditions. Which means: do nothing. Bad comparison - jshint doesn't have an annoying acoustic alarm :)

Comment: I think he may have worded the question incorrectly. It looks like he has a list of specific warnings he wants to ignore. For example, if you are using promises and use the .catch() method, you will get warnings in every single file you handle errors using .catch(). It would be nice to ignore that specific warning globally.

Comment: I think the question is valid. I want to ignore all warnings but one. E.g. I only want to see the warnings about missing semicolons (option `asi: false`). If I only specify the option `asi: false` I still get all the other warnings that are displayed by default. I just want to see the warning about the missing semicolons so I can concentrate on fixing them first. I also don't want to change the JS code by adding a comment `jshint ignore:start` and `jshint ignore:end` like suggested as a solution below. How can I simply specify it in the jshint options?

Answer (score 2):

During development or debugging it can be useful to suppress everything or a part of the file.

Wrap whichever code block you want to ignore in:

```
/* jshint ignore:start */
<code here>
/* jshint ignore:end */
```

Don't forget to remove this pre production though!

Comment: This is also handy if you are including a third-party library, though it's usually better to place them in a non-hinted directory.